# Convert titles to images

Tags: javascript

I want to grab the titles of all the classes named "title" and convert the title into an image.

In console.log it says undefined so i know the problem is somewhere around querySelector.

```
function getImgByTitle() {
  let title = document.querySelector("body .title").innerText;
  let img = new Image();

  img.src = "images/" + title +".jpg";

  console.log(title);

  img.addEventListener("load", function(){
    document.getElementById('headImg').appendChild(this);
  });
}
```

Comment: Improved formatting, title.

Comment: is `getImgByTitle` called before load? That might be your problem

Comment: no, its at the bottom of every parent @mousetail